# Passing variable from .js file to google maps api v3 html

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to show markers in google maps, but it's not working yet. I'm using node.js and express.
So here's my code

First the javascript function, which reads a set of locations from a file, and transforms the whole script

```
var readMonActual = function(){
  var coordsArray=fs.readFileSync("grd2google.txt", "utf8");
  var coordsArray=coordsArray.substring(1,coordsArray.length-1);
  var myCoords=[];
  data=coordsArray.split(',');
  for (var i=0;i<data.length;i+=3){
    myCoords.push([
                    Number(String(data[i]).replace(/\'/g, "")),
                    Number(String(data[i+1]).replace(/\'/g, "")),
                    Number(String(data[i+2]).replace(/\'/g, ""))
                  ]);
  }
  //return {myCoords:myCoords};
  return myCoords;
}
```

Then the function in the html file

```
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(10.191, -68.192),
        zoom: 7,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapOptions);
    var markers=readMonActual(); //<- this returns as undefined
    var marker = new Array(); 

    for(i=0; i< markers.length; i++ ) {
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markers[i][1]), parseFloat(markers[i][2]));
                new google.maps.Marker({
                position: position,
                map: map,
                title: String(markers[i][0])
                });
    }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

The map loads, the .js script loads, but it still doesn't show the markers because the variable that contains the array comes back blank (even though a console.log() of the readMonActual function shows me the array with the locations)

Comment: it sounds like your map initialize function is running too soon.  you should make sure it runs as a callback to the marker reading function if that is a dependency of your application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is being caused by the synchronous file process. `initialize` trying to use data that hasn't been returned yet. I've simplified the functions below a little to save some space. In short, pass a callback function into `readMonActual` that will return the markers once the file process is done.

```
function initialize() {
  // rest of codecode
  // pass in a callback to readMonActual
  readMonActual(function (markers) {
    for(i=0; i< markers.length; i++ ) {
      // do loop
    }
  });
}

var readMonActual = function (callback) {
  var coordsArray=fs.readFileSync("grd2google.txt", "utf8");
  var coordsArray=coordsArray.substring(1,coordsArray.length-1);
  var myCoords=[];
  // the rest of the code
  // return the markers via the callback
  callback(myCoords);
}
```

Comment: i passed the callback to readMonActual but it doesn't accept it, when i go to terminal and do "node app.js" it returns an error saying "undefined is not a function" while pointing to the callback

Comment: oh i just noticed another error, the actual error that may be causing my markers not to show. firefox reads "var fs=require('node-fs');" in the script file i'm importing and just says "require is not defined"... i need the require for node.js though

Comment: What happens if you change it from `var readMonActual = function () {...` to `function readMonActual() {..`?

Comment: nothing, because that's not the error it detects. the thing is i'm mixind node.js with javascript, so, when i create my own modules i have to require node modules, andthe way to do it is, for instance: "var fs = require('node-fs')", and if i want to export a function, it would be "exports.readMonActual = readMonActual"... and when the html view with the map elements loads, it doesn't recognize the words "require" or "exports" as javascript

Comment: If you're going to use nodejs modules in the browser the only way I can think you can do that is with http://browserify.org/